# Protractor: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for spec to complete

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, saucelabs, browserstack

I have several protractor tests and sometimes I get a error saying:

```
Message:
     timeout: timed out after 10000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined
```

It can be randomly happening on some tests.
I usually test on BrowserStack and it shows the error once in 3-5 builds. But recently I tried SauceLabs and almost every (every!) but not all the tests fail with that error. Probably, SauceLabs are just significantly slower so I get the error more often...

So here are the questions:

1. Is there a way in Protractor/Selenium to change test running timeout? It needs to be changed on BrowserStack/Saucelabs as well.
2. Why am I getting the error so often? Is there anything wrong with my tests? Most of the doesn't seem complicated or long running. Again, on local machine it's almost always fine.

Here is the example:

```
   it('should check that login gives error on empty or incorrect email', function () {
      p.get('/#/login');
      p.findElement(protractor.By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();
      expect(p.findElement(protractor.By.css('.alert-danger')).getText()).toEqual('E-mailadres is niet geldig');
      p.findElement(protractor.By.model('user.email')).sendKeys('test-1xtc.vc');
      p.findElement(protractor.By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();
      expect(p.findElement(protractor.By.css('.alert-danger')).getText()).toEqual('E-mailadres is niet geldig');
      p.findElement(protractor.By.model('user.email')).clear();
    });
```

The app is using
AngularJS, selenium 2.20, protractor 0.20.1

Comment: I've been getting timeouts frequently on Sauce Labs, too, and mine is set to 30000 msec.  It really reduces the usefulness of the tests.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is there a way in Protractor/Selenium to change test running timeout?*

Yes :) You can do it via the `allScriptsTimeout` in your Protractor config (from [Protractor FAQ](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/74bc02f3f638bb5ad0e274bb25ebdf1b43d7d577/docs/faq.md))

You can also set the `defaultTimeoutInterval` in `jasmineNodeOpts` option (from [Protractor referenceConf.js](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/cca270c598dbc7e07ae9c74320b110e95dd9f212/referenceConf.js))

> *Why am I getting the error so often? Is there anything wrong with my tests? Most of the doesn't seem complicated or long running. Again, on local machine it's almost always fine.*

Hard to say without seeing your tests. The example you provided looks good to me.

Comment: changing allScriptsTimeout and defaultTimeoutInterval does not work for me

Comment: Hi,  I am also facing the same issue, Any update? were you able to resolve?  Thanks.

Comment: for me also, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Is your project an angularjs project? Are you using any $interval or $timeout service somewhere? If so, try to use $interval instead of $timeout and try to adjust the optional 'count' parameter to be 1, for example (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#usage).
I had recently a similar problem and I solved it this way.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, But I'm using $timeout, because I have a method doing this: After 10 seconds start printing a hello world message for 5 seconds. How can I remove my $timeout in order to get my protractor test running fine?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a different property of `config` file, which I didn't see mentioned in answers above.

```
getPageTimeout : 100000 //in millis, i.e., 100 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

the default time for saucelabs is 90 seconds I believe. it can be changed via your conf.js file using the idleTimeout variable which takes in a value of seconds.  example

```
idleTimeout = 90; // equals 90 seconds
```

---

```
  exports.config = {
  //Includes test sub-sub-foldersbefore any tests in sub folders 
  specs: ['tests/*/*/*.js', 'tests/*/*.js', ],


  // use jasmine 2
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  capabilities :  {
                browserName: "chrome",
                // this takes seconds so 120 would be 120 seconds.
                idleTimeout = 120;
            },
},
```

Now if you need to change the value of a specific spec file you can use this inside your spec file, of course if your saucelabs idleTimeout is lower than this value than it will time out on saucelabs first. or if your saucelabs value is higher but the DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL is lower then it will time out.

```
// this takes in miliseconds so 1000 = 1 second
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 120000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine has timeout for each spec i.e. each `it` in jasmine framework. so if any spec (`it`) exceeds jasmine spec's default timeout then it fails that spec.

**Solution**:
To override jasmine spec timeout for one individual spec, pass a third parameter to it: 
`it(description, testFn, timeout_in_millis)`

```
it('description of test case', function() {
   /*your test 
               steps
                    here*/
},120000);//120 seconds timeout for this spec
```

more information on  [timeouts is here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)